# How to provide a response based on a publisher confirm

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have a web service that ingests objects, sends a notification over AMQP, and returns a JSON response to the requester. Each request is performed on a single thread and I am trying to implement publisher confirms and I am struggling on how I should set it up. I have it working but I don't like the way I am doing it.

The way I am doing it is:

- Put some headers on the message
- Have a publish-subscribe-channel with 2 subscribers
- Subscriber 1) creates a blocking queue so it is ready
  and sends the message over amqp
- Subscriber 2) begins pulling for 5 seconds on that queue until it gets its confirm
- The amqp:outbound-channel-adapter sends its publisher confirms to a service activator
- The publisherConfirmReceiver receives the confirm and puts it in the blocking queue causing the subscriber 2's pulling to complete and return the result of the confirm.

This technique does work properly but I don't like making the assumption that the chain is going to receive the message before the waitForPublisherConfirm Service Activator from the publish subscribe channel. In this case order matters regarding which component receives the message first.

If the waitForPublisherConfirms service activator receives the message first it will just block the thread for 5 seconds, then allow the chain to send the message via the amqp:outbound-channel-adapter.

I tried putting the waitForPublisherConfirms after the amqp:outbound-channel-adapter but since the outbound-channel-adapter doesn't "return" anything so the service activator never gets called after it in the chain.

I feel like there should be a better way of doing this. My goal is to wait for publisher confirms (or a timeout which I cannot find support for in spring's publisher confirms) before sending a response to the requester.

Could you help me shape the solution a little better or let me know if it is OK to rely on the fact that the first subscriber to the publish-subscribe-channel will always receive a message first.

Sorry this one is so long.

Some configuration

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="addHeaders" output-channel="metadataIngestNotifications">
    <int:header name="routingKey" ref="routingKeyResolver" method="resolveReoutingKey"/>
    <int:header name="notificationId" expression="payload.id" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:chain input-channel="metadataIngestNotifications" output-channel="nullChannel" >

    <int:service-activator id="addPublisherConfirmQueue"
        requires-reply="false"
        ref="publisherConfirmService"  
        method="addPublisherConfirmQueue" />

    <int:object-to-json-transformer id="transformObjectToJson" />

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter id="amqpOutboundChannelAdapter"
        amqp-template="rabbitTemplate"
        exchange-name="${productNotificationExchange}"
        confirm-ack-channel="publisherConfirms"
        confirm-nack-channel="publisherConfirms"
        mapped-request-headers="*"
        routing-key-expression="headers.routingKey"
        confirm-correlation-expression="headers.notificationId" />

</int:chain>

<int:service-activator id="waitForPublisherConfirm"
        input-channel="metadataIngestNotifications"
        output-channel="publisherConfirmed"
        requires-reply="true"
        ref="publisherConfirmService"  
        method="waitForPublisherConfirm"  />


<int:service-activator id="publisherConfirmReceiver" 
                       ref="publisherConfirmService" 
                       method="receivePublisherConfirm" 
                       input-channel="publisherConfirms" 
                       output-channel="nullChannel" />
```

Class

```
public class PublisherConfirmService {

    private final Map<String, BlockingQueue<Boolean>> suspenders = new HashMap<>();

    public Message addPublisherConfirmQueue(@Header("notificationId") String id, Message m){
        LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("Adding publisher confirm queue.");
        BlockingQueue<Boolean> bq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        suspenders.put(id, bq);
        return m;
    }

    public boolean waitForPublisherConfirm(@Header("notificationId") String id) {
        LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("Waiting for publisher confirms for Notification: " + id);
        BlockingQueue<Boolean> bq = suspenders.get(id);
        try {
            Boolean result = bq.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if(result == null){
                LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()).error("The broker took too long to return a publisher confirm. NotificationId: " + id);
                return false;
            }else if(!result){
                LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()).error("The publisher confirm indicated that the message was not confirmed. NotificationId: " + id);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()).error("Something went wrong polling for the publisher confirm for notificationId: " + id, ex);
            return false;
        }finally{
            suspenders.remove(id);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void receivePublisherConfirm(String id, @Header(AmqpHeaders.PUBLISH_CONFIRM) boolean confirmed){
        LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("Received publisher confirm for Notification: " + id);
        if (suspenders.containsKey(id)){
            BlockingQueue<Boolean> bq = suspenders.get(id);
            bq.add(confirmed);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Should I maybe be using the rabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback in some way or is that how the outbound-channel-adapter implements its confirm-ack-channel/confirm-nack-channel stuff anyway.

Comment: Just answered my comment:
public class AmqpOutboundEndpoint extends AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler
  implements RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback.....
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-amqp/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/amqp/outbound/AmqpOutboundEndpoint.java

Answer (score 0):

How about to take a look to the Aggregator solution for the same purpose?

The `<recipient-list-router>` to send message to the aggregator's `input-channel` and the second channel for the `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

The `confirm-ack-channel` must be something which brings the message to the same aggregator after some transformation, e.g. a proper extraction for the `correlationKey` and so on.

Comment: I don't mind the way that the correlation is being done, I am just worried about the order in which the subscribers on the publish subscribe channel are being invoked. Are you saying that by using an aggregator it wouldn't matter what order the events occur? Is an aggregator an `asynchronous` service?

Comment: You can specify the `order` attribute on each subscriber if you worry that your XML definition may have vulnerability.

Comment: Order! I did not know about the order attribute. That solves the whole problem though I will look at the aggregator. I have not used that yet so I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Does `order` work for you? Do you ready to `accept` the answer to close the question ?

Comment: This sounds like another use case for the [process barrier enhancement](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3736) that I raised for your earlier question (link in the JIRA). I don't think the aggregator will help because it does not suspend a thread until the group is complete.